# "window.angular is undefined." when using protractor for automated testing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I seem to have an error when using the example `conf.js` provided with protractor.
I am running my tests with `grunt-protractor-runner` but it errors even when using the example config provided.

My `Gruntfile.js` looks like this:

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
      protractor: {
        options: {
          configFile: "smoketest.conf.js", // Default config file
          keepAlive: false, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
          noColor: false, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
          webdriverManagerUpdate: true,
          args: {
            seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.51.0.jar'
          }
        },
        smoke_test: {   // Grunt requires at least one target to run so you can simply put 'all: {}' here too.
          options: {
            configFile: "smoketest.conf.js", // Target-specific config file
            args: {
              }
          }
        },
        protractor_test: {   // Grunt requires at least one target to run so you can simply put 'all: {}' here too.
            options: {
                configFile: "./node_modules/protractor/example/conf.js", // Target-specific config file
                args: {
                }
            }
        },


      },
    })

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-runner');
  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['protractor:smoke_test']);

};
```

I am running `grunt protractor:protractor_test` which uses this file:

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  it('should greet the named user', function() {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('Julie');

    var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));

    expect(greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
  });

  describe('todo list', function() {
    var todoList;

    beforeEach(function() {
      browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

      todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    });

    it('should list todos', function() {
      expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(2);
      expect(todoList.get(1).getText()).toEqual('build an angular app');
    });

    it('should add a todo', function() {
      var addTodo = element(by.model('todoList.todoText'));
      var addButton = element(by.css('[value="add"]'));

      addTodo.sendKeys('write a protractor test');
      addButton.click();

      expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
      expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write a protractor test');
    });
  });
});
```

however, when this runs i am presented with the error

```
Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"`enter code here`
```

I have been to http://git.io/v4gXM but i cannot seem to find anything to fix my issue? Has anybody else had this issue, surely the example test should work always??

Comment: reverted back to an older version of protractor (last known to work with our test scripts) and it works...?

Comment: possibly due to `Jasmine` try to switch to use `Jasmine2` next time if you got the similar issue. (There are many possibilities for this, but easiest solution is using jasmine2)

Comment: I am also getting a similar error after upgrading Protractor.  For me, I did not get this error in 3.1.1, but I got other errors, so I was hoping that 3.2.1 would fix those errors.  But with 3.2.1 I am running into this exact error.  I thought it may be due to the fact that my ng-app directive is on the html element and not the body element.  But adding rootElement: 'html' to my Protractor config did not help.  https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1742

Answer (score 9):

Exclaimer!!:  This doesn't answer your question as such but provides a hack to solve it.

Protractor requires the Angular page to finish synchronization before it runs it's expectations. Therefore, in order to work around this issue you can use:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.waitForAngular();
browser.sleep(500);
```

This tells the browser that protractor opens to not wait for the Angular to synchronize (ignoreSynchronization), then it waits for angular to finish everything else it's doing, then it adds a 500 millisecond wait to give protractor a chance to find `addButton.click()`. When the wait finishes, it forces protractor to move onto the next line of code which contains your expect, before this, it was stopping at the `addButton.click()` line and waiting for the sync (which wasn't happening), before it moved on.

(I think...)

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem (Protractor 3.1.0 with Jasmine2). It seems to me that the `browser.get()` in your `beforeEach()` call is the culprit.
Copying that to each test could be a workaround.

Comment: That was just the example script, I do the browser.get() in my own tests as you say and still get the same error.

Comment: In the answering section it says: "Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer."

Answer (score 0):

i faced same issue and it resolved for me :-

```
1. downgrade protractor to 3.0.0
2. add jasmine2 in conf.js
```